# Command to find how much is the space in that directory leaving the files created in last 7 days. Without using `find`

Tags: linux, awk

I don't have appropriate access to the system in order to run the privileged `find` command. So I am trying to get a string of commands possibly using `grep` or `awk` or anything that could list me the files that where NOT created within last 7 days and how much space are they consuming.

I came up with this command `du -h | grep ^[0-9.]*G` now I need to know how can I list which once are more than 7 days older.

Output of the above command is:

```
du: cannot read directory `./lost+found': Permission denied
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy1.extranet.akamai.com
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy2.extranet.akamai.com
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy5.extranet.akamai.com
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy6.extranet.akamai.com
1.1G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-sp01.extranet.akamai.com
1.2G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-sp02.extranet.akamai.com
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy7.extranet.akamai.com
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy8.extranet.akamai.com
1.1G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-sp03.extranet.akamai.com
1.1G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-sp04.extranet.akamai.com
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy3.extranet.akamai.com
1.5G    ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs/p3-proxy4.extranet.akamai.com
18G ./portal/portal-internal-crons/get_portal_logs
18G ./portal/portal-internal-crons
18G ./portal
19G .
```

Comment: Try `ls -t`, that will give you a timestamp.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen its not working for along with my output. If it was that simple I would have not posted here.

Comment: What about using `stat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can run `ls -lR --time-style=+%s` on the target, you could:

```
ls -lR --time-style=+%s | awk -v now=$(date +%s) '/^-/ && now - $6 > 7*24*3600 {s += $5} END {print s}'
```

Explanation: `ls -lR --time-style=+%s` produces this kind of output:

```
.:
total 7168
drwxr-xr-x 2 john doe    4096 1439992030 dira
drwxr-xr-x 2 john doe    4096 1441870671 dirb
-rw-r--r-- 1 john doe   43980 1436264423 filea
-rw-r--r-- 1 john doe   15941 1436264418 fileb
-rw------- 1 john doe 7193171 1439374938 filec
-rw-r--r-- 1 john doe    2927 1436264418 filed

./dira:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 john doe 1205 1439991207 filea
-rw-r--r-- 1 john doe  142 1439990672 fileb

./dirb:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 john doe 116 1441870658 filea
```

where the last modification date is a timestamp in seconds. The `awk` code selects the lines corresponding to files (first field starting with `-`) which timestamp is more than 7 days in the past. It accumulates the sizes (field number 5) of the selected lines and prints the sum at the end. The age of a file is computed as the difference between the current timestamp (`awk` variable `now`) and the file's timestamp (field number 6). The current timestamp is passed to `awk` as variable `now` with the `-v now=$(date +%s)` option.